# How to add UserControl to ListView on Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, user-controls

I'm trying to make it so, for each item on a `List<>` , a usercontrol gets inserted into a ListView.
I tried doing the following but it didn't work:

```
foreach (var item in MyList)
            {
                UserControl1= new UserControl(parameter);
                listView1.Items.Add(UserControl1);
            }
```

However, it marks an error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
> 'UserCOntrol' to 'string'

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to solve this problem?
Thank you for your time!

Edit: this is what I have on my usercontrol

[This is my UserControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymdIJ.png)

Edit 2: my code looks like this now:

```
foreach (var item in MyList)
            {              
                FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(new UserControl(parameter));
            }
```

Comment: '*What am I doing wrong?*' You cannot add a control to an `Item`, you should add a control to `Controls` collection of another control/form. '*What can I do to solve this problem?*' Well, `listView1.Controls.Add(new UserControl1(parameter))` works. But the question is, why do you want to do that? Why are you not using a DataGridView, a TableLayoutPanel or other possible options?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you for your help. I'm using a list view because the UserControl is serving the purpose of a layout

Comment: Your solutions didn't quite work. It no longer gives me any error. It just doesn't show the UserControl on the ListView

Comment: Layout purpose, is not a good reason. You can use a TabelLayoutPanel or a DataGridView instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a `FlowLayoutPanel`, instead of list view, as the list view does not add `UserControls`.
e.g.
`flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(new UserControl());`

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work. Nothing shows

Comment: You have a flow layout panel on your Form, where you then use your code to add user controls to the flow layout panel.Is there anything on the designer for the user control you've created?

Comment: yes, I have. I can even show a print screen

Comment: I'd need to see more of the code to be able to help more

Comment: What part do you need? Is there a specific part?

Comment: I've made some more edits

Comment: the code to add user controls to your flowlayoutpanel

Comment: Added! Its not much

Comment: you should change it to flow lay out panel, not table.

Comment: It is, Im stupid and wrote the wrong thing on StackOverflow